# Intuitive explanation for RMS voltage of discontinous sinewave

Tags: signal-processing, rms, signal-theory, sine

A sinewave with a peak voltage of 325.3V. The RMS voltage would be 230V
[image: continous_sinewave]

**Assumption1:**
If I were to run this AC sinewave through a resistor it would be the same power dissipated as running 230V DC through it.

**Assumption2:**
If I have a 230V DC signal that I instead switch on and off with a duty cycle of 10%. I would expect the power dissipated would be 10% of that when the 230V DC is always on.

[image: 10_duty_cycle_single]

[image: 10_duty_cycle_multiple]

**Assumption2_cont:** If added some capacitance and switched fast enough the signal would show 23V on a voltmeter.

[image: pwm_circuit]

Now if instead of the switched DC signal, we have a discontinuous AC signal, that is active 10% of the time and deactivated 90% of the time. I would assume that the power dissipated is 10% of that when it is always on. However when calculating the RMS of such signal, the output is not the 23V RMS as I assumed, but instead 72V RMS.

[image: discontinous]

**Assumption3:** Now I realize that it has to do with the fact that the number of samples are are also added inside the root function.

[image: rms_calc]

But I cant get an intuitive feeling as to what the RMS voltage actually represent with the discontinous signal.

The signals are generated with matplotlib, see below for code. The script can be run with and without continous using the "--fault" argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Description")

parser.add_argument("--fault", "-f", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()

def rms(array):
    '''
    Calculate root mean square
    '''
    sum_of_squares = 0
    for i in array:
        i_val = i
        sum_of_squares += i_val * i_val

    elements = len(array)
    return math.sqrt(sum_of_squares/elements)

cycles = 10

t = np.arange(0, 2*math.pi * cycles, math.pi/50)
amplitude = 325.3
sine = amplitude * np.sin(t)

if args.fault:
    percent_time_before_fault = 0.1
    fault_start = int(len(sine) * percent_time_before_fault)
    for i in range(fault_start, len(sine)):
        sine[i] = 0

plt.plot (t, sine, "r")
plt.title("RMS voltage:{:.2f}".format(rms(sine)))

if args.fault:
    plt.savefig('interrupted.png')
else:
    plt.savefig('continous.png')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you make your actual question a bit clearer: what do you want to know?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, make the sampling at least 10x the highest frequency, so that the errors are small(er), aka GoodEnough®.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen The samples are from "math.pi/50" so it would be 100 samples in each sinewave cycle. Or have I missunderstood what you meant?

Comment: As an example of pulsed power calculations vs. changing the voltage, see [Can I connect 12V halogen bulb to a 60V battery?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/617147) re: DC = peak vs. RMS of the AC.  I seem to recall another question about using a very high DC voltage PWMed to drive a low voltage motor, with the voltage-squared ratio meaning that the necessary PWM duty cycle was fractions of a percent, and the currents would be huge (so heating and magnetic flux stuff would be a problem), but I can't find that Q&A now.

Answer (score 6):

> If I were to run this AC sinewave through a resistor it would be the same power dissipated as running 230V DC through it.

Indeed: that is both the definition and the intuitive explanation mentioned in the title.

> If added some capacitance and switched fast enough the signal would show 23V on a voltmeter.

Not sure what is meant by that (in series, in parallel?). Assuming a large enough capacitor in parallel with the voltmeter and some series resistance in the voltage source, you would obtain the average voltage, which is zero for the signal without an offset.

> I would assume that the power dissipated is 10% of that when it is always on. However when calculating the RMS of such signal, the output is not the 23V RMS as I assumed, but instead 72V RMS.

The RMS voltage in that single cycle is 230V. The energy dissipated in that cycle is proportional to the square of this voltage. Divided by 10, to get the average of the whole period, and calculating the square root to go back to voltage, you have:

$$
\sqrt{\dfrac{230 \times 230}{10}} = 72,7323862
$$

Answer (score 5):

> *If I were to run this AC sinewave through a resistor it would be the
> same power dissipated as running 230V DC through it.*

Correct

> *If added some capacitance and switched fast enough the signal would
> show 23V on a voltmeter.*

Average is not the same as RMS. A voltmeter averages the voltage normally.

The 72 volts RMS for a 10% duty sinewave is correct (bar a few decimal points).

Comment: "Average is not the same as RMS." This one hit me like a truck. I thought it was exactly that.  I though RMS voltage was; "over time this ac voltage is the same as this dc voltage"

Comment: @Heneer It is the average power, not the average voltage. This may be the source of the confusion.

Comment: @Heneer imagine your pulsed dc voltage pulsed positive and then pulsed negative. The power would be exactly the same as if it only pulsed positively but, the average voltage would be zero.

Comment: @Andyaka: (I checked the image in the edit history and) it's the absolute value of the final signal plotted in the question.  So its energy is equal everywhere as `x^2 == (-x)^2` but the average is quite different.  Not very helpful except directly contrasted with the plot in the question.

Comment: I deleted a comment as it was in response to another now deleted comment and the pair belonged together.

Comment: @devnull This is a comment, NOT a complaint: If adding substantially to someone else's post I consider (and opinions may vary) that it's useful to note within the post that the content was not by the OP*. eg I may put ~~= "Added - RM"  or similar. Adding or removing substantive material, as opposed to minor edits, is not outside the rules, but needs to be done with due care for the feelings of the OP. Again, just a comment.
* In this case the change related to what the OP had said in comments. Care still needed.

Answer (score 5):

The Power is proportional to the square of the voltage.
The square of 72.74 is exactly 10 percent of the square of 230.02.

Comment: What you sai is true and relevant - but it may help some people iof you explain in somewhat more detail how that applies here.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon in the initial version of the question there was mainly the following: "However when calculating the RMS of such signal, the output is not the 23V RMS as I assumed, but instead 72V RMS."

Comment: Yes. That is still there in the fine print. I have no complaint at all with what you wrote, and I agree with what you are explaining. However, I think it quite likely that the OP may not follow what you are saying but that a bit more detail may assist. This is not a complaint of any sort - just a suggestion. (You already had my upvote before I wrote this).

Answer (score 4):

Let's be a little more formal about this. The RMS of time continuous signal of length T (or a periodic one with period T) is defined as

$$x_{RMS}= \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T x(t)^2dt}$$

For a signal DC signal the RMS is the same as the DC itself (since we are integrating over a constant). For a sine wave that comes out to be the peak value divided by
\$\sqrt{2}\$.

Discontinuous can get a little more complicated. Let's say we shut the signal off at time \$t_1\$. Then the RMS becomes

$$x_{RMS}= \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T x(t)^2dt} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_0^{t_1} x(t)^2dt} = \sqrt{\frac{t_1}{T}\frac{1}{t_1}\int_0^{t_1} x(t)^2dt} = x_{RMS,t_1}\sqrt{\frac{t_1}{T}}$$

where \$x_{RMS,t_1}\$ is the RMS of the orginal signal truncated to length \$t_1\$. For a 10% duty cycle  we have \$t_1 = 0.1T\$ and hence

$$x_{RMS} = x_{RMS,t_1}\sqrt{0.1}$$

For a discontinuous sine wave with peak voltage of 325.5V that comes out to be 72.78.. V BUT ONLY if the remaining part of the sine wave is an integer number of periods (or quarter periods to be precise). If the sine wave part is a fractional number of quarter periods, you would get a different result.

Comment: I'm actually shocked that the concept of integration over time was not mentioned in the very first comment and instead the entire thread is "square this, root that". :-)

Answer (score 1):

One way to intuit what RMS voltage "means" is to consider one of the ways it could be measured in the days before RMS conversion chips: using a matching pair of lightbulbs and rheostats.  Connect one bulb and rheostat in series with the voltage to be measured, starting with the rheostat at the maximum resistance, and adjust the resistance downward until the bulb starts to glow.  Connect the matching bulb and rheostat connected to an adjustable DC reference voltage and adjust that voltage until the glow of the second bulb matches that of the first.  The RMS voltage applied to the first bulb will match that applied to the second (which will in turn equal the applied DC voltage).

Note that because this is a "balance-based measurement", the electrical characteristics of the bulbs and resistors, including temperature coefficients, won't matter provided that both rheostats are close enough to the same temperature that their resistances match, bulbs that are glowing equally will have the same resistance, and the thermal time constant of the bulbs is much longer that the period of the waveform to be measured.  The accuracy of matching may be confirmed by using a 4PDT switch to swap the voltage being measured with the reference, and confirming that swapping in that fashion doesn't affect the relative brightness of the lights, nor the applied reference voltage (e.g. by changing the load resistance seen by the reference supply).